# Jquery hides container when it should be showing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an h3 tag when a sibling div's children are all display:none. However, when just the sibling div is not visible, jquery hides my h3 tag even if the div's children are visible. Ideas?

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00ofvxor/

html:

```
<h3 class="EventsContainer">H3</h3>
<div class="EventsContainer" style="display:none;">
    <ul>
        <li class="StatusContainer" style="display:none;">LI1</li>
        <li class="StatusContainer" style="display:none;">LI2</li>
        <li class="StatusContainer">LI3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.EventsContainer').css('display',function(){
        var children = $(this).find('li.StatusContainer');
        if (children.length === children.not(':visible').length)
        {
            $(this).prev().css('display', 'none');
            return 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            return 'block';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Its because you set your parent `div` to `display:none` which makes `:visible` return false for all children. So `children.length === children.not(':visible').length` wil be true

Comment: Alright, do you know how I would check the children for their visibility even if the parent div is set to hidden?

Comment: demo doesn't make sense... any descendent of hidden element is also hidden. `div.EventsContainer` is hidden so nothing within it will be `:visible`

Comment: @MaxBuster, do you have a specific reason to have the parent div not visible while having the children div visible?

Comment: Do your check when you unhide the parent `EventsContainer`

Comment: I do, the div is a pop down in the actual website, so it will always be hidden  on page load but then I hide some of the children lis even when it is popped down.

Comment: Because it's a pop down, it could be either hidden or visible when I want to check.

Comment: are you trying something like this https://jsfiddle.net/00ofvxor/1/??

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the `display` value. Map the `children` and return them if they have `display:none`:

```
...
var children = $(this).find('li.StatusContainer');
var hiddenChildren = children.map(function() { 
    if ($(this).css('display') === 'none')
        return $(this)
});
if (children.length === hiddenChildren.length) { 
    ...
}
...
```

Which should give you what you need.

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uwtdy8h/)